# Javascript - How to move focus from one textbox to another in Javascript after the previous text box is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am writing one Javascript code

Please see the images. There are 4 text boxes where only one character can be entered .

The rightmost field's id is first and the leftmost id is fourth

4 conditions are to be fulfilled

The last text box - the rightmost/first textbox will be input first, then the second one will be filled , then the third and at last the fourth

Then the rightmost/first textbox value will shift (left shift) to the second and in this way values will shift until all 4 fields are filled  - See screenshot Insert

If we place the cursor on any other element except the first/rightmost it will move the cursor to the rightmost because we will only enter input in the rightmost

There will be backspace function which will delete the rightmost/first , ie. the the first field will be deleted the fourth field value will move to third, third to second , like this , a right shift will occur in this way all elements are to be deleted  - see Screenshot Delete

**In delete the cursor is not staying in rightmost position , I have place the cursor again & again to delete**  - Please again refer Screenshot Delete

**During insertion - When the value will move to second from first the second one should remain focus ,right now the first one/rightmost is always remaining focused , i mean during insertion the cursor will always stay in the first but the focus should move from right to left one by one**

**The entire solution should be in Javascript , no JQuery can be used**

[Screenshot Insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8eUg.jpg)

[Screenshot Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl8Gg.jpg)

```js
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var myEditable = document.getElementById("first");

for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
  myInputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("first").focus();
  })
}

myEditable.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  /****
   *  A few things are handled here: we can check if
   *  the input is a numeric, and we can check if the input
   *  is a backspace. Nothing else is allowed.
   ****/
  if (evt.which == 8) {
    // If a backspace has been pressed, move all the input
    //  values one field UP.
    myEditable.blur();
    for (var i = myInputs.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      myInputs[i].value = myInputs[i - 1].value;
    }
    myInputs[0].value = "";
  } else if (evt.which >= 48 && evt.which <= 59) {
    // Here, we have a number. Everything gets shifted to the LEFT

    if (myInputs[0].value == "") {
      for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length - 1; i++) {
        myInputs[i].value = myInputs[i + 1].value;
      }
      myEditable.value = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry");
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="fourth" size="1" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" id="third" size="1" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" id="second" size="1" maxlength="1" />
    <input type="text" id="first" size="1" maxlength="1" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all I would change the name of the fields to a prefix+numeric format (id="field0", id="field1", etc), this can simplify the problem a lot and you can perform the checkings on a loop. Even, if you know that there are only 4 fields (being the number  the one on the left), you can decide in each one of them how to move to the previous one.

Comment: The cursor does not stay in the rightmost input on delete because you tell it not to using `myEditable.blur()`. Unless you have not explained it well, the cursor **should** stay in in the first box during insertion. The cursor appears in the box with focus: you can't "focus" the second box and leave the cursor in the first box.  I see an answer has been posted with the code correction.

Comment: @Traktor53  i am happy that he solved that but still one problem remain. but the focus problem is not solved During insertion - When the value will move to second from first the second one should remain focus ,right now the first one/rightmost is always remaining focused , i mean during insertion the cursor will always stay in the first but the focus should move from right to left one by one

Comment: @Traktor53 he told its not possible ? Is it really impossible ?

Comment: @Carles When the value will move to second from first the second one should remain focus ,right now the first one/rightmost is always remaining focused , i mean during insertion the cursor will always stay in the first but the focus should move from right to left one by one , only this problem remains

Comment: Why don't you disable the other textboxes or you replace them with divs with the same appearance? You can keep a shallow copy of the whole value in a variable and split information on the boxes based on key events on the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Have  look to this.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input3" onfocus="HandleFocus(this)" onkeypress="return HandleKeys(event, this)" value="" style="width:40px">
<input type="text" id="input2" onfocus="HandleFocus(this)" onkeypress="return HandleKeys(event, this)" value="" style="width:40px">
<input type="text" id="input1" onfocus="HandleFocus(this)" onkeypress="return HandleKeys(event, this)" value="" style="width:40px">
<input type="text" id="input0" onfocus="HandleFocus(this)" onkeypress="return HandleKeys(event, this)" value="" style="width:40px">
```

Javascript:

```
function HandleFocus(obj)
{
    if (obj.id.indexOf("0")==-1) {
    document.getElementById("input0").focus();
  }
}

var content = "";
function HandleKeys(e, obj)
{
    if (obj.id.indexOf("0")!=-1)
  {
    var c = e.which;
    if ( (c==8)&&(content.length>0) ) {
        content = content.substr(0, content.length -1);
    } else if ( (c>=48)&&(c<=57)&&(content.length<4) ) {
        content += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
        document.getElementById("input" + i.toString()).value = (i>=content.length) ? "" : content[content.length-1-i];
  }
   return false;
}
```

You can run it in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j22uwaps/5/)